# Desktop Integration in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, windows, desktop, win-universal-app

Im trying to develop an app for Windows 10 which I hope to submit to the store. I want to get access to the Taskbar APIs so I can set the progress level (green bar behind the process text).

In Windows 7 I used the some of these APIs: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391692(v=vs.85).aspx

They were wrapped by this handy library which I used in my C# app:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2009/02/12/windows-7-taskbar-apis/

I cant find the equvilant for UWA Desktop Extension, Any ideas?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Basically the images are comes from the app asserts, see this: [Guidelines for app assets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt412102.aspx) **Target-based assets** session for more information. The asserts are the read-only stuff and we cannot programmatically change from the code, which means we cannot create the animation on taskbar.

The APIs like ITaskbarList3 are not available in Windows Universal App.

Basically base on my understanding, Microsoft wants to use push notification/live tile also badge to deliver the current state like current progress.